# How to Change the Default ViewController Class Declaration in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, syntax, uiviewcontroller

As i've grown as a developer, I've developed my own way of styling and managing my ViewControllers and I was hoping there was a way to change the default ViewController. Being able to customize the default ViewController syntax would save me a considerable amount of time down the road.

Creating a new ViewController:
[image]

What i get:
[image: Default ViewController]

What i want:
[image]

Comment: I would create a code snippet

Comment: Investigating - Looks promising!

Comment: There are _lots_ of tutorials on making a custom template. Please search before asking.

Comment: Did you consider creating a common *superclass* instead of intentionally generating duplicated code?

Comment: @matt But there is zero information on it here on Stack, which is my most trusted source of truth. It's how I learn best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and with the help of this post, it appears there's two viable options - coordinator patterns & code snippets

**Coordinate Patterns**

Tutorial: [Custom Xcode Template](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/158/how-to-create-a-custom-xcode-template-for-coordinators)

Although the coordinator pattern is doing exactly what is being asked, it appears to be a fairly lengthy and complicated process when compared to code snippets

**Code Snippet**

Awesome Reference: [Xcode Snippets](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-create-code-snippets-in-xcode/)

By highlighting all of the code that is defined in my default ViewController, right-clicking, and selecting "Create Code Snippet", I was able to define a new snippet which can be accessed by clicking the "+" on the top right corner of Xcode (with focus being on a swift file and not a storyboard file) You can even define Keywords for the autocompletion to work off of.

Comment: that is what i said from the begining and my link i shared.. anyway happy to work

Answer (score 0):

As I know you need to create a custom Xcode project template. And your customized ViewController file needs to use this custom Xcode project. It is used for some design patterns sample.

In my opinion if you really use this template again and again worth it creating one otherwise it could be little painful